# What is the text for "the other second-term course in analysis at MIT?"

Tags: textbooks, mathematical-analysis

My question comes from first few paragraphs of preface of "Analysis on Manifolds" by James R. Munkres, as excerpted below:

> A year-long course in real analysis is an essential part of the
> preparation  of any potential mathematician. For the first half of
> such a course, there  is substantial agreement as to what the syllabus
> should be. Standard topics  include: sequence and series, the topology
> of metric spaces, and the derivative  and the Riemannian integral for
> functions of a single variable. There are a  number of excellent texts
> for such a course, including books by Apostol [A],  Rudin [Ru],
> Goldberg [Go], and Royden [Ro], among others.
>
> There is no such universal agreement as to what the syllabus of the
> second  half of such a course should be. Part of the problem is that
> there are simply  too many topics that belong in such a course for one
> to be able to treat them  all within the confines of a single
> semester, at more than a superficial level.
>
> At M.I.T., we have dealt with the problem by offering two independent
> second-term courses in analysis. One of these deals with the
> derivative and  the Riemannian integral for functions of several
> variables, followed by a   treatment of differential forms and a proof
> of Stokes' theorem for manifolds in  euclidean space. The present book
> has resulted from my years of teaching  this course. The other deals
> with the Lebesgue integral in euclidean space and its applications to
> Fourier analysis.

As says by the third paragraph, the text "Analysis on Manifolds" by James R. Munkres is the text for one of the two independent second-term courses in analysis at MIT. But the text for the other second-term course having different syllabus ("Lebesgue  integral in euclidean space and its applications to Fourier analysis") in parallel with "Analysis on Manifolds" is not mentioned. If you happen to know (or enrolled in), can you please tell me what textbook is used for this "other second-term course in analysis at MIT"? It would be more than appreciated if you can also let me know its course number and the link to a course website of "the other second-term course in analysis at MIT." Thanks a lot.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is off topic.  I am not sure where it would belong/

Comment: Have you tried asking the mathematics department at MIT? That might get you further than hoping to strike it lucky here. Good luck!

Comment: I'm wondering if this question is actually outdated.  Geometry of smooth manifolds remains a central part of mathematics, but analysis with non-smooth real-(vector)-valued functions, especially the more technical aspects, seems to be a much less popular topic than it was 40 years ago (especially when you get farther away from functional analysis).  In particular, I'm not sure who on their faculty now would teach such a course, though I'm very far from analysis and might not be able to tell.

Comment: MIT still has a two term model for analysis, where the first class 18.100 is roughly as described. There are now three alternatives for the second class: 
18.101 "Analysis and Manifolds", 18.102 "Introduction to Functional Analysis" and 18.103 "Fourier Analysis: Theory and Applications". You can read brief course descriptions here http://student.mit.edu/catalog/m18a.html .

Comment: Oddly, though, I can't find out the textbooks! The catalog listing for 18.102 says "No required or recommended textbooks", but the others say nothing. I also checked https://math.mit.edu/academics/classes.html?term=2022SP&show=text and http://catalog.mit.edu/subjects/18/ . And, in a sign that things have very much changed, thecoop.com doesn't seem to have a textbook section of their website at all!

Comment: There are versions of all of these courses on open course ware: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-103-fourier-analysis-fall-2013/ https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-101-analysis-ii-fall-2005/ https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-102-introduction-to-functional-analysis-spring-2009/ although, as you can see, they are all about a decade old. I am a huge fan of the OCW project, and I think it is very sad that, when I look up a MIT current course, it is now usually on Canvas instead of MIT's own, much better, OCW system.

Comment: @David E Speyer: Thank you so much for the helpful comments which contains valuable links. I traced back to Spring 2005 and I believe "Lebesgue Integration On Euclidean Space" written by Frank Jones is the textbook for "the other second-term course", because it covers measure theory in its main body, while touches Fourier transform and series in two chapters. After that, the textbook seemed to be chosen based on instructor's personal preference. I don't have the option to upvote your comment for now, but I will in the future when I have the right. PS, I totally agree with you on Canvas.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo you wrote that analysis with non-smooth functions seems less popular now compared to years ago. The non-smooth functions in the OP are from Lebesgue integration.  That is still a fundamental part of analysis (Fourier analysis, probability, etc) and anyone in analysis should be qualified to teach measure theory and integration.

Comment: @KCd I think AlexanderWoo might be talking about things like vector-valued differential forms with coefficients that are distributions rather than functions.